# browser.version returns 8.0 for IE10

Tags: browser, internet-explorer-10

I user $.browser.version to verify my IE version using JQuery.

when the code executes on IE10 it returns 8.0?

Any suggestions...

Answer (score 0):

Try checking if IE is in compatibility mode, by opening the developer tools (F12) and looking at the drop downs at the top of the tool. It is probably in IE8 compatibility mode. Make sure you use a valid doctype, and if all else fails, add the following to the head of your page:

```
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```